# Power Query: Re-bind a Query to a Worksheet / Table that has been Deleted and Re-Created

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, power-query

I am using Power Query in Excel for Microsoft 365. I am using VBA, rather than the graphical interface, to perform Power Query operations.

Assume I have an existing workbook, with that workbook containing two tables, `Source_t` and `Sink_t` (in worksheets named `Source_w` and `Sink_w`, respectively), and that I have a query named `Sink_q` that takes data from `Source_t`, performs some transformations on it, and loads the results into `Sink_t`.

Please consider the following VBA code:

```
Sub BindQueryToWorksheet()
    DeleteWorksheetIfExists "Sink_w"
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Sink_w"
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteWorksheetIfExists(WorksheetName As String)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets(WorksheetName).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

When the VBA code deletes `Sink_w` (and, in so doing, `Sink_t` as well), `Sink_q` turns into a "Connection Only" query. When the VBA code re-creates `Sink_w` and performs a refresh all, `Sink_t` does not get re-created (and obviously, the query's output does not load because there is no table to load it into).

But `Sink_w` does get re-created, and I can then use the Power Query graphical interface's "Load To..." option to create a table in `Sink_w` and load data into that table. (But note, the name of the created table is `Sink_q`---the same name as the query---not `Sink_t` as needed. If I manually rename the table to `Sink_t`, things still work as expected when I do a refresh all.)

### My Questions

In VBA, how can I:

1. Bind `Sink_q` back to `Sink_t` such that a refresh all will create `sink_t` (in worksheet `sink_w`) and populate that table?
2. Control the name of the created table so that it is `Sink_t`, not `Sink_q`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Wrapper`, as defined below, will delete and re-create a worksheet and will then re-bind a query to it as a data source.

```
Sub Wrapper()
    BindQueryToWorksheet DestinationWorksheetName:="Sink_w", _
                         DestinationTableName:="Sink_t", _
                         SourceQueryName:="Sink_q"
End Sub

Private Sub BindQueryToWorksheet( _
                                    DestinationWorksheetName As String, _
                                    DestinationTableName As String, _
                                    SourceQueryName As String _
                                )

    DeleteWorksheetIfExists DestinationWorksheetName
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = DestinationWorksheetName
    Range("A1").Select

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add( _
                     SourceType:=0, _
                     Source:="OLEDB;" & _
                             "Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;" & _
                             "Data Source=$Workbook$;" & _
                             "Location=" & SourceQueryName & ";" & _
                             "Extended Properties=""""", _
                     Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
                                    ).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & SourceQueryName & "]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = DestinationTableName
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteWorksheetIfExists(WorksheetName As String)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets(WorksheetName).Delete

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```